# HTMX Active Search - min of 3 characters

Tags: search, request, htmx

I'm following along with the [HTMX Active Search](https://htmx.org/examples/active-search/) example.
I need to change it so it does not trigger the request unless 3 characters have been entered in the search input box.

```
<input class="form-control" type="search" 
   name="search" placeholder="Begin Typing To Search Users..." 
   hx-post="/search" 
   hx-trigger="keyup changed delay:500ms, search" // can I add something here to only trigger if 3 or more characters are entered
   hx-target="#search-results">
```

I know can deal with this on the server side i.e. abort the request if fewer than 3 characters are entered, but I'd rather avoid the round trip and server call.
Having said that, I do not want a js solution either :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [docs](https://htmx.org/docs/#trigger-filters):

```
The "this" symbol will be set to the current element.
```

So you should be able to do:

```
keyup[this.value.length > 3] changed...
```

Comment: Sweet, that did the trick. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may try to include `hx-validate` attribute and use HTML5 validation API:

```html
<input class="form-control" type="search"
   hx-validate
   min-length="3"
...>
```

as per [documentation](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-validate/).

Comment: Unfortunately this still triggers the event (the input control is not contained within a form tag so that might be the problem)